# How to shift the position of some characters within an XMl File

Tags: mac, xml, dictionary

I am trying to edit an XMl file belonging to a custom mac dictionary prior to undergoing the "make" and "install" commands. Here is an example of the code I am dealing with:

```
<d:entry id="_15qc" d:title="fabulous">
<d:index d:value="fabulous" d:title="fabulous"/><h1>fabulous</h1><font color="#007000">adjective</font><br/>
['fab·u·lous || 'fæbjʊləs]<br/>
wonderful, marvelous; unbelievable; legendary, imaginary; from a legend
</d:entry>
```

What I intend to do is to change the position of [`'fab·u·lous || 'fæbjʊləs]<br/>` so that the phonetics of the word appears right after title of the word. Just like below:

```
<d:entry id="_15qc" d:title="fabulous">
<d:index d:value="fabulous" d:title="fabulous"/><h1>fabulous</h1>['fab·u·lous || 'fæbjʊləs]<br/>
<font color="#007000">adjective</font><br/>
wonderful, marvelous; unbelievable; legendary, imaginary; from a legend
</d:entry>
```

Are there any XML editors which let me do so for all the entries of this long file?

Comment: Is the format predictable enough to use search and replace in notepad++ or whatever? find `</h1><font color="#007000">adjective</font><br/>` and replace with `</h1>` and replace `]<br/>` with `]<br/>
<font color="#007000">adjective</font><br/>` would work on your sample data... do all the entries follow the same syntax?

Comment: Only in so far as the entry is an "adjective"

Comment: Somehow I completely missed that. Well. I guess you could repeat the pair of search + replace for each part of speech. That's all I've got.